# Trigger mobile notification of task creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, asana

I'm joining my app to `Asana` and I'm creating automatically tasks. I would like to notify assigned user to his new task.
I didn't find anything about that from [Asana API documentation](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#followers)

Does anyone have an idea to trigger a mobile notification? Is that even possible?

Comment: Not possible - that's outside the scope of the API. A mobile notification would only happen through an Asana mobile app - and the user would have to explicitly subscribe to these types of notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a task, you can assign it, or add followers to it, or even add a comment to it. But push notifications are logic the *user* controls, rather than the integration. If I want to be notified of new tasks assigned to me, I will be.

Comment: You're right. If notification are enable on user's phone, it will be showed. I didn't way enough to see it and I directly thought it was not working when you create a new task from the API. Thanks !

Comment: Note that if the API creates a task *for the user it's authorized as* they won't receive a notification ("you" assigned the task, so we don't notify you that it's been assigned to you). To make sure notifications are always sent out it's best to use a "bot" user authorized as the API.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done after understanding that I'm not notify myself if I assign me a task. Thanks !